# SGS i9000 runing devil kernel JB gets keyboard error + play store error

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s, 4.1-jelly-bean, keyboard

so about 3 months ago i flashed my phone for the first time using devil kernel (im still a noob with this stuff) and one day writing a message I clicked the "speaker" (the one you get to speak to your phone and it wright what you say) button and since then the message "unfortunatly your android keyboard stopped" or something apears , but before that i got this weird message every time i tried to download an app from the play store. 
is there anything i can do or is it best to just reset and re-install everything again? thanks

Comment: The kernel just implements the touch screen driver, if the keboard app crashes, that's a userland problem. Give some more info please: Rom, Android Version, GApps version (gapps-xx-20xx...zip). You also need to do this: Use logcat to view the crashlog and debug yourself or create a pastebin and link here. Without detailed info there's no possibility to help. If you need a keyboard, you can install an alternative one (e.g. one of [those](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=keyboard&c=apps)) and use that in the meantime.

Comment: Logcat is part of the Android SDK, but there are also apps to view the logs on the device itself. A windows program is also here, but you also need some drivers probably: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1618882